# How To Parse html String from UIWebview for richtexteditor in iphone

Tags: iphone, html-parsing, richtextediting

I am using RichTextEditor exactly as detailed in this [link](http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/rich-text-editing-a-simple-start-part-1/) and I need to show the written content in table view in other class on a button click, but in the table view cell, corresponding html string is appearing. Following is my code

```
-(void)submitClicked{
  contentObject.webCOntent=webView;
            contentObject.savedMessage=SAVED;
            contentObject.str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                         @"document.body.innerHTML"];
            NSLog(@"created  %@",contentObject.str);
}
```

in tableView cellforRowAyIndexPath,

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[notesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]str ];
```

When I run the app,its Showing in tableview 
     Oiuo8

where, contentObject is modelclass object and str is string and webcontent is `UIWebView`  in model class

Comment: What does your NSLog statement say?  How are you getting contentObject into notesArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution finally by changing   contentObject.str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                         @"document.body.innerHTML"]; to
 contentObject.str = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: 
                         @"document.documentElement.textContent"];,its giving the normal text instead of html text.